# (SQL) Trying to Make A Trigger That Maps Data To a Historical Table Generically With Error Checking

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables at the current moment, located in two different schema dbo.table1 and historyschema.table1history. I have created a trigger that moves all historical data from table1 (upon insert, delete, and update) to table1history.

I originally tried to design the trigger to transfer the information with a INSERT INTO [historyschema].[table1history] select @columns...

Explicitly stating all columns to transfer, but since the two tables have the exact same columns (except history has an extra creation_timestamp and creation_status) I wanted to add them generically with a select * statement. I did this because then when the database has a column added I don't want to have to go back and manually change the trigger every time.

I need a try/catch statement in case there is an error but it doesn't work because the error obtained isn't caught by try/catch (The Error Obtained is Implicit Conversion because of wrongly aligned tables). I was wondering if there is a way to iterate through the columns of table1 and make sure the columns are formatted in such a way where the information will not create an error when being put into table1history.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[table1_History_Change] 
ON [dbo].[table1]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @Now AS DateTIME = GETDATE()

    SELECT *
    INTO #ModifiedTemp
    FROM 
        (SELECT 'I' *, creation_status, @Now creation_timestamp
         FROM inserted
         UNION
         SELECT *, 'D' creation_status, @Now creation_timestamp
         FROM deleted) SubQuery

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ModifiedTemp WHERE creation_status = 'D') > 0 
       AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ModifiedTemp WHERE creation_status = 'I') > 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM #ModifiedTemp 
        WHERE creation_status = 'D'

        UPDATE #ModifiedTemp 
        SET creation_status = 'U'
    END

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [HistorySchema].[Table1History]
            SELECT * 
            FROM #ModifiedTemp
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'History unsuccessfully saved (ERROR: bundle_procedure_change)'
        DROP TABLE #ModifiedTemp
        RETURN
    END CATCH

    DROP TABLE #ModifiedTemp
```

(This is my first posts so if you have any criticisms to help me to improve they are appreciated :).)

NOTE: If the tables are formatted incorrectly I want the trigger to simply not create the history but follow through with the transaction on the main table.

Comment: This seems way over complicated. But the real issue is that your select statements for the inserts are in different orders (and the first one is not valid because you are missing a comma after the string literal 'I'. You really don't need all this complication in here. You don't need a temp table, a variable for the current time. This entire thing could be reduced to a single insert statement.

Comment: Oops I must have mixed that up while formatting it should be *, 'I' creation status

Comment: Regardless this just doesn't need to be this complicated. But I can't quite wrap my head around what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I might have added to much information, but what I'm trying to do is create a log of historical data in one table (table1history) with all of the information in the row of table1 (using a trigger) being updated, inserted or deleted. I also want to indicate whether it was 'I' Inserted, 'D' deleted, or 'U' Updated as well as the timestamp of when the it happened.

Comment: You can easily determine this with a single full outer join between inserted and deleted. Then when i.ID IS NULL it is deleted, when d.ID IS NULL it is inserted, else it is an update.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire trigger can be simplified to something close to this. I don't know what columns you really have. You should NEVER use * here because if your base table changes your trigger is broken. Be explicit with columns.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[table1_History_Change] ON [dbo].[table1]
    after update, insert, delete as

    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO [HistorySchema].[Table1History]
    (
        CreationStatus
        , creation_timestamp
        , Col1
    )
    select CreationStatus = case when i.ID is null then 'D' when d.ID is null then 'I' else 'U' end
        , creation_timestamp = getdate()
        , isnull(i.Col1, d.Col2) --this will get the new values for inserted and updated or the current value for a delete
    from inserted i 
    full outer join deleted d on d.ID = i.ID
```